# Please help get my stuck ETH back? Metamask

Tags: ether, metamask, etherscan

I'm hoping someone can help.

I tried to mint some NFTs and my transaction got stuck in pending. Let's call this "Transaction #1". It was for 0.1332 ETH.

After about an hour, it showed as "Dropped" in Etherscan, but it was still showing as Pending in Metamask. I had no ETH left to cancel it so it was just stuck there. After a little while I started getting nervous, because the transaction was dropped, but my ETH did not return back to my account, so I started looking for ways to speed it up.

I found a video that suggested that the best way to do this is to create a new transaction of sending 0 ETH to yourself (so you have a minimal gas fee) and using a Nonce that is +1 the Nonce of your stuck transaction. I did that. Let's call this "Transaction #2".

As soon as I did that I noticed that Transaction #1 was showing 0 ETH (ie. it was overridden by the amount for Transaction #2).. I then tried to cancel that transaction and was successful because it showed me a cheaper gas fee that I could afford. The transaction was successfully canceled.

The end result is that Transaction #1 now shows as canceled and for 0 ETH. Transaction #2 shows as successful. The money is not back in my account.

Is there any way I can get it back?

For your reference, see the log of Transaction #1
Transaction created with a value of 0.1332 ETH at 12:02 on 9/11/2021.
Transaction submitted with estimated gas fee of 0 WEI at 12:02 on 9/11/2021.
Transaction submitted with estimated gas fee of 0.001 ETH at 13:14 on 9/11/2021.
Transaction cancel attempted with estimated gas fee of 0.001 ETH at 13:15 on 9/11/2021
Transaction successfully cancelled at 13:15 on 9/11/2021

Goes without saying that I would really appreciate any help here. It's a lot of money.

Thank you!

Comment: What's the transaction hash? If a transaction hasn't been mined the ether should still be in your account. Check the account balance using a different wallet or in a block explorer. Since it says dropped did you try to replace it? Using nonce + 1 will not replace a transaction, to replace it has to be the same nonce.

Comment: You may also want to "Contact Support" at https://metamask.zendesk.com

Answer (score 1):

If you want to cancel a transaction, don't use +1 Nonce value. Actually replace the nonce value to the nonce value of the transaction you want to cancel.

EX. If the stuck transaction's nonce value is 5; then create a new transaction sending 0 ETH to yourself, but customize its nonce to be 5 as well.

Answer (score 1):

Thankfully nothing is taken from your account for a pending transaction that gets dropped and replaced.
Any eth missing was either used for gas fees or removed in a transaction that successfully landed on chain.

You can use a balance tracker to look at how much eth you had at each given block number: https://etherscan.io/balancecheck-tool

Use a block explorer to go through your transactions, do the math by adding up the values spent on gas or maybe taken for an NFT:
https://etherscan.io/

Use the state change tab on the transaction page, or use the state changes shown on the balance tracker, to confirm.